# Tomcat 6.0 updates

Tags: tomcat, deployment

So I am trying to update my index.jsp file in my eclipse, and after I do that, I rebuild the project with clean and install and on Tomcat6.0 on the tomcat manager, I click the reload button and reload the war file again but the updated info doesn't appear when I click the link, I tried undeploying it as well and reloading it but same result. THANKS

Comment: Delete browser cache, as well and check if the jsp servlet (tomcat_home/conf/web.xml) does not have a property development=false set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is:

1. Right click on the Tocmat Server -> Clean Tomcat work directory...
2. Right click on the Tocmat Server -> Clean

Also try making the Tomcat publishing settings to true:

- Automatically publish when resources change

Server options setting to true:

- Modules auto reload by default

This usually helps me (sometimes you don't even need to restart the server - just refresh the browser - it depends on what you're changing and your Tomcat configuration).